# Ionic 4 ng-container y ng-template no me refleja el Botón

Tags: html5, angular, botón, ionic4

Estoy realizando un botón que cambia de seguir - siguiendo en un listado de personas, lo estoy haciendo por un componente  y

Inicialmente me salió un error que solucioné colocando CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA en el module, pero ahora no me sale ni el botón ni error para identificar, no se si tenga que ver con CUSTOM... o me falte algo.

el componente html es el siguiente:

user-relationship

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isFollowing | async; then unfollow else follow">

</ng-container>



<ng-template #unfollow>
    <ion-button ion-button round 
    (tap)="Afs.unfollow(currentUserId, followId)">

    Unfollow
  </ion-button>
  </ng-template>


  <ng-template #follow>
      <ion-button ion-button round outline
      (tap)="Afs.follow(currentUserId, followId)"
      [disabled]="isOwner">

     Follow
</ion-button>
    </ng-template>
```

Y el page donde se mostraría el botón sería el siguiente.
search-profile

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
        <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
      </ion-buttons>
 <!--   <ion-searchbar placeholder="Buscar Perfil" showcancelbutton="" (ioninput)="filterList($event)"></ion-searchbar>
 -->
</ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding >

    <ng-container *ngIf="afAuth.user | async as currentUser">

        <ion-list>
            <ion-item *ngFor="let user of users | async; trackBy: trackByFn">
              <ion-avatar item-start>
                <img [src]="user.photoURL">
              </ion-avatar>
              <h2>{{ user.displayName }}</h2>
              <ion-button [currentUserId]="currentUser.uid"
              [followId]="user.uid">SEGUIR</ion-button>
              <user-relationship [currentUserId]="currentUser.uid"
              [followId]="user.uid">
              </user-relationship>

            </ion-item>
          </ion-list>

    </ng-container>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: No parece haber problemas en tu logica. La consola no te da ningun error?

Comment: No me sale ningún error, simplemente no aparece el botón y esto es lo que me parece extraño.